# sudo svn up update not happen after following command

Tags: svn, ubuntu-14.04

sudo svn up command shows following output in ubuntu terminal and svn reopsitory not updating

Updating '.':
At revision 4285.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these commands:

```
svn revert -R .
svn update
```